# Dictionaries on iOS 9 not working

Tags: ios, dictionary, language

I just updated to iOS 9, and I noticed that the built-in dictionaries, I previously used, aren't working. I had used American English, British English, and Apple Dictionary. Now, when I try to define any word, I get a "No definition found" error. The dictionaries I previously used show a blue circle (while all the others show the cloud download icon).

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Comment: I had the same issue, so annoying

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug to me. Not even iOS is completely immune to them, even after a long public beta period. So, not a lot that you can do other than wait for iOS 9.0.1 and hope that it will fix that issue with the dictionary.

Comment: Any ideas if this has been fixed in 9.3.3, I tried all the suggestions in tried all the suggestions in [this answer] (http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/210483/10733) with no luck.

Answer (score -3):

I was also facing the same issue...just go to Settings->General->Reset->Reset All Settings. This will solve your problem.

Comment: That doesn't fix the downloaded dictionaries that define words, only the user dictionary which affects spelling / autocorrect.

Answer (score -3):

I was so sad when this happened to me because I practically have no vocabulary It's an easy fix though you go to settings->general->reset->reset keyboard dictionary.

Trust me it won't do anything bad. I freaked out when I saw you have to reset it but you only have to reset the dictionary keyboard to work. A plus is that it still has your dictionaries downloaded and ready to go after you've reset it

Comment: That doesn't fix the downloaded dictionaries that define words, only the user dictionary which affects spelling / autocorrect.