# Why I can't use the 'define' button after updating to iOS 9.0.2?

Tags: ios

I just updated my iPhone to iOS 9.0.2, then I want to define some words. When I clicked the 'define' button, there's nothing appear. But, before I updated to iOS 9.0.2, I still can use the define button. So what should I do to allow it to define the words I want?

Answer (score 5):

Go to **Settings -> General -> Language & Region** -> and make sure the languages you want your iPhone to recognize are in the "Preferred Language Order" list.

If the language you prefer is already in that list, tap "edit" to delete the language, and then add it back up. This should add the language's dictionary and enable the "define" function.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I click 'manage' and saw the blue circle beside the language which is English-British, English-America, and Apple Dictionary. What is the meaning of the blue circle???

Comment: I just click on the other language and it's work !! I try to delete them and download them back. I hope it works.

Comment: Okay it works !! All I have to do is manage it back. Delete them and reupload it. Then I try to define it back and it works !! Thanks btw

Comment: Awesome :). I've edited my answer to include deleting the language and then adding it again. If you could upvote my answer, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings->General->Reset->Reset Keyboard Dictionary.

Tried every other suggestion, this works.

Answer (score 0):

High light the word, his define then hit manage. Download the dictionary in the language you want from there  and try again. Should work

Comment: Hitting manage shows nothing but a blank page with lines like ruled paper.